# How to generate an Excel XML file with correct date format?

Tags: ruby, xml, excel

I am trying to generate an XML file through Ruby:

```
<ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="DateTime">2014-09-15</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
```

However it displays in Excel as a number, like `41249` that bears no resemblence to the original date. If I right click the cell, and change the format to DD.MM.YYYY or whatever, then it displays the correct date. Anyone know how I can set the format in the XML for how the date is displayed? The data is there, it's just being displayed incorrectly.

Comment: Please share the code that generates this XML.

Comment: @mudasobwa Out of curiosity, why would the code matter?

Comment: If you think code does not matter, why you tagged it `ruby`?